# Place or attach permanent file to the node edit form

Tags: forms

I want to make an attachment available for download to the user who is filling out a node edit form. This attachment will be a file template that they will fill out, save, then upload to the filefield field at some point, so I want the attachment to ALWAYS be available on the node edit form.

I realize I could do this by placing a block on the page via the block admin ui, but I would like to accomplish this using `hook_form_alter`, because the file that is attach will be specific to certain field within that form having certain values when a user is editing the form. I've provided a visual mock-up for further clarification.

[image: Form Expample]

Comment: Do you have any specific question with using hook_form_alter?

Comment: I was able to figure it out by using hook_help

Comment: landing, if you figured it out, please post an answer with the solution and mark it accepted to help future visitors

Answer (score 1):

If it's a PDF, you might also want to look into [Fill PDF](http://drupal.org/project/fillpdf).